# Нужно ли обособлять деепричастный оборот в заданном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

***Я полночи провела (,) бегая по всему этажу.***

Можно ли в заданном предложении не обособлять деепричастный оборот, объясняя это тесной связью со сказуемым?  Или здесь нет тесной связи?

Запятая, вероятно, нужна, но как корректно доказать это? Распространенность  оборота желательно не учитывать, так как это не принципиально в данном случае (можно заменить: бегая повсюду).

Кстати, у "тесной связи" есть хотя бы какое-нибудь **определение,** как она выглядит? Я слышу этот термин довольно часто, но не уверена, что каждый раз эта связь понимается одинаково.

Answer (score 2):

Это вполне можно интерпретировать как образ действия:
*Я полночи провела (как?) бегая по всему этажу.*

Пример Розенталя: *провести ночь не смыкая глаз*.

Как такие моменты Розенталь объяснял? В таких случаях основной смысл предложения в обороте: важно не то, что провёл ночь, а то, что бегал по всему этажу.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113 (см. примечание 1, там пояснения такого типа)

Да и при изъятии оборота предложение становится некорректным.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Так вы не хотите обособлять?  Странно,  в постановке запятой я как-то не сомневалась.  Нет, oleedd, давайте обособим. Послушайте еще раз предложение, обратите внимание на его структуру, на порядок слов...  И скажите, что вы передумали.

Comment: А зачем вы задали вопрос, если не сомневались? Он как раз и существует для того, в чём сомневаются. Понимаю, что ударение на "повела" звучит (в этом плане хочется поставить запятую), но остальное всё против. Дело в том, что это не два разных действия и в обороте даже не сопутствующее действие, как в примере Розенталя, это одно действие: бег по этажу — это времяпровождение. С запятой — разговорный вариант. В разговорном стиле многие принципы нарушаются.

Comment: Выбрать знак и объяснить знак — это разные вещи. Я сомневалась в том, как корректно объяснить постановку запятой. Придумала версию, но не уверена в ней.

Comment: А у вас вопрос звучит совсем иначе :)

Comment: Я тоже против запятой, хоть и пауза есть. Привет всем!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Стоп. Если нет запятой, то нужно читать без паузы и ударения. Тогда получается единое действие, а не *проводила полночи и бегала по всему этажу*.

Comment: @Sharon А тут у вас как? *Я полночи провела(,) бегая.*

Comment: @oleedd *Если нет запятой, то нужно читать без паузы и ударения*. – нет, так не пойдет. Произносительная пауза вовсе не означает постановку запятой. И вообще, я же в этом моменте за вас. Пауза здесь может быть минимально-минимальная. *Я полнОчи провела / бегая по всему этажу.*

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ладно, просто не в курсе об этой "произносительной паузе". Для меня все паузы отражаются в пунктуации. Может, не знаю каких-то нюансов, но и прочитать об этом негде. В примерах Розенталя она тоже у вас есть? Если так, то всё в порядке.

Comment: Нет, в примерах и правилах я не припомню, чтобы об этом говорилось. Просто из практики чтения, особенно в длинных предложениях, точно можно видеть, что препинание в речи далеко не всегда отражается на письме, то есть эти произносительные паузы никак нельзя обосновать грамматически.

Comment: Sharon, и для вас, конечно, скажу. Если мы делаем о-очень заметную паузу и ***бегая по всему этажу*** читается как присоединение с монотонной интонацией, то запятая уместна. Видимо, за вариативностью будущее! Главное – доступность в понимании. Снова возвращается мысль о том, что у нас не хватает знаков препинания для отражения всех нюансов речи. P. S. Интересно, "монотонная интонация" – так вообще можно говорить? Посмотрю.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец "Монотонная интонация" — вполне (*очень однообразный по тону, интонации*). Вы не сказали о "произносительной паузе" в примерах Розенталя (второй абзац пункта 6).

Comment: Ага............

Comment: Прочитал еще раз. Там в основном нет этих пауз. Они, на мой взгляд, присутствуют в следующих примерах. *Сергей отстранил Веру, кивнул ей и ушёл / посвистывая. Мимо них не пройдёшь / не порадовавшись. Не торопясь / он прошёлся по комнате.*

Comment: И опять же, прочитав много раз по-разному, прихожу к выводу, что в зависимости от ударения на определенном слове можно либо "паузироваться", либо "не паузироваться". Ведь мы **не слышим** пишущего. Например, так: *Сергей отстранил Веру, кивнУл ей / и ушёл посвИстывая.*

Comment: Между словами промежутки гораздо больше, чем между буквами. Меньше всего они между предлогом и примыкающим к нему словом. Притяжение между разными словами отличается. Думал, вы об этом, а не о паузах от ударений (которые должны отражаться пунктуационно). Тут фишка в том, что без запятой ударение переходит с глагола на деепричастный оборот. Как бы один вариант пунктуации предполагает один вариант ударений (в этих случаях).

Answer (score 1):

***Дорогие коллеги и друзья, большое вам спасибо за внимание к вопросу.*** Я с большим интересом прочитала вашу дискуссию, и она меня очень порадовала. Вот это настоящий подход к русскому правописанию.

**1. НЕМНОГО ТЕОРИИ**

Интонационный принцип в пунктуации очень важен, но специалисты-теоретики уделяют ему мало внимания, так что приходится изучать **практику**. Интонационные схемы – это первый шаг, и пока еще не очень совершенный. Недостаток таких схем – в их **статичности**, в условности, в то время как реальная интонация изменчива, **наполнена движением**.

В этом отношении мне ближе **позиция Александра** – у него хорошая интуиция, и  он чувствует **эту динамику** (вспомним его *вариативность, нюансы, минимально-минимальную паузу и  паузу о-очень заметную*). Я также думаю, что существует тесная связь между тоническим (логическим)  ударением и последующей паузой: **чем отчетливее ударение, тем длиннее пауза.**

**Произносительные паузы** всегда присутствуют в речи (мы не можем говорить на одном дыхании), при этом они соответствуют определенным речевым отрезкам.  Каждый такой отрезок имеет свое определенное по силе  ударение (выделение  голосом). Но произносительные паузы невелики по длительности, мы не обозначаем их знаками.

**Грамматическая пауза** – это уже более длительная и четкая пауза, которая обозначается запятой или другим знаком (об этих паузах говорит **oleedd**). В этом случае ударение  усиливается и становится фразовым/тоническим (всего одна ударная позиция на всю фонетическую фразу). Сложное, а также осложненное предложение состоит **из двух или нескольких таких фраз**, разделенных знаками.

А дальше вот что интересно. В некоторых случаях граница в определении произносительной и грамматической паузы  **становится размытой**. Достаточно немного изменить структуру, добавить или переставить слово  (а это зависит от конкретной ситуации), как **произносительная пауза перейдет в грамматическую** и потребует для себя знака препинания. Вот такие ситуации обычно и вызывают споры.

**А замечания у меня такие.**  *Цитирую: «…в зависимости от ударения на определенном слове можно либо "паузироваться", либо "не паузироваться". Ведь мы не слышим пишущего…*»

Как правило, мы его все-таки слышим… :)

Не стоит думать, что мы очень **свободны в своем прочтении текста** и можем делать паузы по своему желанию. Иногда случается такое (два варианта произношения и разная пунктуация),  но чаще автор, выбрав структуру предложения, **задает нам его прочтение**. Чтобы мы поняли его мысль, угадали его образ, его отношение к сказанному. Вот это – **живая ткань словесности**, к ней надо относиться бережно и с пониманием.

Наши жесткие схемы постановки знаков (исключительно по правилам, без учета интонации и семантических оттенков каждого случая) могут  **исказить художественную мысль.**

**Правила – это закон**, мы обязаны его соблюдать, но надо понимать эти правила. Даже в настоящий момент (при несовершенной редакции общего свода) там **достаточно возможностей**  для корректного  объяснения тех знаков, которые мы ставим **с учетом интонации**.

**2. ПРАКТИКА**

Теперь по поводу текста, там такая драма… :)

– *Где ты был, почему не позвонил мне?! **Я полнОчи провела,// бегая по всему этажУ.**  В отеле тебя точно не было.*

Или такая:
– *Где ты была, я никак не мог дозвониться*?!

–  *Дел в отеле было много. **Полночи  я провела / бегая по всему этажУ**, // а потом докумЕнты оформляла.*

Это как бы иллюстрация к теории: произносительные (/) и грамматические паузы (//), расстановка ударений.

Мы видим, как всё это зависит от общей структуры предложения, так что получаются **два варианта**. Все правы?  Но я-то  немножко правее? :)   Запятая ставится **в заданном самостоятельном предложении**, а при отсутствии запятой пришлось изменить структуру.

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, то есть право на два ударения (на подлежащем и сказуемом): первое смещается с местоимения на "полночи", а второе падает на оборот: *Я полнОчи провела бегая по всему этажУ.* Запятая будет ставится, если ударение будет на глаголе, но это разговорный вариант.

Comment: Немного не так.  В простом предложении  у нас ИНВЕРСИЯ,  при этом ударная позиция смещается с конца фразы на середину: Я полнОчи провела, // бегая по всему этажУ.  Но если взять сложное предложение, то там наше простое предложение превращается в одну фразу с ударением на последнем слове, то есть как раз на обстоятельственном обороте (тогда обособления нет). Таким образом, если вы как автор не хотите обособлять оборот, то надо поставить его в ударную позицию, а не просто по смыслу не обособлять.

Comment: Если вы как редактор проверяете пунктуацию, то надо эту позицию  проверить в готовой структуре, расставив там ударения.

Comment: Вы мне не ответили, как у вас с: *Я полночи провела(,) бегая.*

Comment: Его можно включить в состав ССП, а для самостоятельного предложения его структура выглядит некорректно.  Контекст  непонятен, ситуация неясна. Если это простое предложение, то оно должно делиться произносительной паузой на две смысловые части по схеме тема – рема (предмет – сообщение предмете, о чем говорится – что говорится). И для обособления  (постановки двух ударений)  его структура тоже плохо подходит. Получается ни то ни се.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что при наличии по обе стороны вокруг глагола двух обстоятельств (одно из которых — деепричастный оборот, выражающий образ действия) запятая ставится?

Comment: Мне кажется, что мы о разном говорим.  Это предложение не делится на две части ни в одном из вариантов (обособленном или необособленном). Нам неудобно ко второй части относить одно слово (без разницы какое). А если распространить деепричастие, то предложение делится на части, но при этом запятую надо ставить, потому что там два ударения.  А если предложение входит в ССП, то там ничего делить не надо. Всем правит структура, даже лексическое наполнение не важно, если структура уже выбрана.